# Maven: profile properties not be picked up when running test

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

In pom.xml, I define a property:

```
 <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>local</build.profile.id>
                <serverBaseUrl>http://127.0.0.1:8080</serverBaseUrl>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
```

And the `serverBaseUrl` was referenced in file application-email.xml:

```
<bean id="MailService" class="someclass">
        <property name="aurl" value="${serverBaseUrl}"/>

    </bean>
```

I expect that, when running test, using IntelliJ IDEA or using Maven test, ${serverBaseUrl} can be pick up from pom.xml automatically. However, it does not work like what I expect.

When not running test, the thing works exactly what I expect.

What's the problem here? Does maven or IntelliJ IDEA won't pick up profile properties when running test by default? How can I pick up profile's properties when I running the test?

Currently, I have a workaround: Define `serverBaseUrl=xxx` in config.properties and the property is picked up. This is a little ugly what I want to avoid.

Comment: Please post the entire `pom.xml`.  If not possible, please post at least the `build` section. Anyway, Spring  is expecting to find those values in a properties file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more like a shot in the dark, I could not test it.

Add the `resources` tag in the `build` section of your `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
.....
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
             <includes>
                <include>application-email.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
....
  </build>
```

I suppose your `application-email.xml` is inside `src/test/resources` folder.